# react native update specific object where id = id

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have here an array of datas. And I want to update the title from the object where the key is 3.

```
  const data = [
    {
      key: '1',
      title: 'Title 1',
      desc: 'Desc 1',
      image: 'http://192.168.0.22:3000/build/photo_1621612104216_d747ced4-b313-4687-b9ac-ab5bcd78501d.jpg'
    },
    {
      key: '2',
      title: 'Title 2',
      desc: 'Desc 2',
      image: 'http://192.168.0.22:3000/build/photo_1621612230526_f49f2be8-6fd6-420d-b0b0-b39216418924.jpg'
    },
    {
      key: '3',
      title: 'Title 3',
      desc: 'Desc 3',
      image: 'http://192.168.0.22:3000/build/photo_1621612230526_f49f2be8-6fd6-420d-b0b0-b39216418924.jpg'

    },
    {
      key: '4',
      title: 'Title 4',
      desc: 'Desc 4',
      image: 'http://192.168.0.22:3000/build/photo_1621612104216_d747ced4-b313-4687-b9ac-ab5bcd78501d.jpg'

    },
  ];
```

How I make it?
..............
.............
............
..........
...........
............
..............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is just one of many ways to do it:

```
const newData = data.map(({ key, title, ...datum }) => key === "3"
    ? { key, title: "newTitle", ...datum }
    : {key, title, ...datum}
);
```

Comment: Careful with this method as `{key, title, ...datum}` creates a new object for the elements that ***aren't*** being updated. This will have the likely side effect of always being rerendered by React even though the value remains the same.

Comment: Actually, as far as I understand, the `map()` function will always create new objects no matter what.

Comment: No, unfortunately that is incorrect. `.map` shallow copies the array, i.e. it creates a new array reference, but all the elements are shallow copied, meaning they are copied references to the existing elements of the old array. React uses shallow reference equality to help in the reconciliation process, in other words, if the state/prop references the same object as the previous render it can optimize and bail on rerendering that part of the DOM. If you always create new objects then you are making React work harder and do unnecessary work. Depending on the work this can have adverse effects.

Comment: Yep, tested it on code sandbox, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you would map the previous array to the next array, checking the current `key` property for a match, and when found you copy also the element and update the `title` property, otherwise just pass through the current element.

```
const newData = data.map(el => el.key === '3' ? {
  ...el,
  title: // the new title
} : el);
```

This is such a common pattern in React that you would extract this functionality into a function.

```
const updateTitleByKey = (key, title) => {
  return data.map(el => el.key === key ? {
    ...el,
    title
  } : el);
};
```

Another example using dynamic keys:

```
const updatePropertyByKey = (key, name, value) => {
  return data.map(el => el.key === key ? {
    ...el,
    [name]: value
  } : el);
};
```

```js
const data = [
    {
      key: '1',
      title: 'Title 1',
      desc: 'Desc 1',
      image: 'http://192.168.0.22:3000/build/photo_1621612104216_d747ced4-b313-4687-b9ac-ab5bcd78501d.jpg'
    },
    {
      key: '2',
      title: 'Title 2',
      desc: 'Desc 2',
      image: 'http://192.168.0.22:3000/build/photo_1621612230526_f49f2be8-6fd6-420d-b0b0-b39216418924.jpg'
    },
    {
      key: '3',
      title: 'Title 3',
      desc: 'Desc 3',
      image: 'http://192.168.0.22:3000/build/photo_1621612230526_f49f2be8-6fd6-420d-b0b0-b39216418924.jpg'

    },
    {
      key: '4',
      title: 'Title 4',
      desc: 'Desc 4',
      image: 'http://192.168.0.22:3000/build/photo_1621612104216_d747ced4-b313-4687-b9ac-ab5bcd78501d.jpg'

    },
  ];

const updatePropertyByKey = (key, name, value) => {
  return data.map(el => el.key === key ? {
    ...el,
    [name]: value
  } : el);
};

const newData = updatePropertyByKey('3', 'title', 'Title 3 New');
console.log(newData[2]);
```